# C's heritage: bitwise operators vs equality operators precedence

Tags: javascript, c, bit-manipulation, equality

I've stumbled in a JavaScript situation where bitwise operators were used. Logically, a bitwise operator should have a higher precedence than an equality operator, e.g.

```
if val & 10 == 10
   alert('flag set')
```

But it looks like that this code would work the other way, as in JavaScript bitwise operators have lower precedence than equality operators do (see [Mozilla's JS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)). 
The code above would always return `0` for any valid numerical val, because the result of `val & true` is `0`. So, the proper way would be to put parenthesis around bitwise expression:

```
if (val & 10) == 10
   alert('flag set')
```

I dug up the history of the question and it seems like this behaviour comes from the age of K&R's C, where logical `&&` and `||` operators were added after bitwise ones. 
In terms of logical statement in C:

```
if (x == 1 & y == 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Makes perfect sense. But it doesn't make any in terms of bitwise logic.

C++, Java, Objective-C, PHP, C# and finally Javascript have it the same way. 
Python, Ruby, Go have it the other way around.

Do you know any reasons (apart from the one that comes from C's heritage) which made programming languages' designers to follow C's precedence rules?

Comment: Who claims that the whole-value boolean operators were added to C after the bitwise ones?

Comment: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html

Comment: Ok, convincing enough :)